# ORACLE - How to know if any view is using a table?

Tags: oracle, view

I'd need to know if a table is used in any view. I already tried to select from VIEWS but the query will give me an error:

> *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*

I'm not even sure that selecting from views is an oracle thing..

Is there any way?

Comment: "*I'm not even sure that selecting from views is an oracle thing*" - of course you can select from a view. A view wouldn't make much sense if you couldn't select from it.

Comment: not from a view, from VIEWS. It was supposed to be a table with all the views and their definition :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out what views (and other objects) reference a table with this query:

```
select name, type from user_dependencies
where referenced_name = 'MYTABLE'
and referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: Yep, that's it.
By the way, if it's only one table you need to check, once you open it there is the DEPENDENCIES tab that'll tell you every object using it.

This is way better cause it'll allow me to use the like operator!